# Unable to Render ContentControl inside Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I think I am missing something simple here.

This is what I want:
I want to create a MainWindowViewModel instance mwVM.
I want to associate this instance to the MainWindow.

I want to associate the view instance to the viewModel1 member of mwVM.
Thus, I actually want to pass a hierarchy of instances from viewModel in the View. So far, I am unable to see just view.

I am trying to render a custom ContentControl inside a WPF Window.
When I put MainWindow.xaml as entry point of the application, I don't see anything. But when I put view1.xaml as the entry point (in App.xaml), then I can see the text "Hello". What is it that I am missing here?

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MimicView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MimicView"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowViewModel}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
        <local:View1/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding viewModel1}"></ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
namespace MimicView {
class MainWindowViewModel {


    public MainWindowViewModel() {
        this.viewModel1 = new ViewModel1();
    }

    public ViewModel1 viewModel1 { get; set; }
}
}
```

View1.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="MimicView.View1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MimicView"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:ViewModel1}">



<TextBox Text="Hello"/>
```

App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="MimicView.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MimicView"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>

</Application.Resources>
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. But the code you show above sets the data context for your window only when the code is running in the designer. If you are asking why you don't see the user control at run-time, well...that would be the reason. You need to set the data context then too. Often, you won't even need `DesignInstance`...that's only for when you need a specially-populated model object for design-time. In many cases, the regular view model works fine during design time; in other cases, that it doesn't isn't an impediment to designing the UI.

Comment: I want to render view1 inside the mainWindow and associate that view1 to the viewModel1 member (which comes from the MainWindowViewModel instance associated with this MainWindow).
When I hit run, nothing shows up, that is the problem.

Comment: I tried putting DataContext inside the mainwindow, inside the MainWindow.xaml.cs and both. In Neither case does my view1 show up

Comment: also put a comment in question on what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `DataContext` property of the window:

```
<Window x:Class="MimicView.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MimicView"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowViewModel}"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ViewModel1}">
            <local:View1/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding viewModel1}"></ContentControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This only sets the *design time* `DataContext`:

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:MainWindowViewModel}"
```

You should also set the actual `DataContext` property:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```